# Collection storing more than it's intended to causing problems for a Union statement

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

For some reason every column with data is being stored into columnsToCopy and unionVariable. At the top levels in Locals, I can see that it recognizes the column I actually want, but when I go deeper into say Cells -> WorkSheet -> UsedRange -> Value2 it will now show that all columns in my workbook are stored. This is the piece of code that I have assigning columnsToCopy, all the way to assigning unionVariable and then Copying it:

```
checkOne = iq_Array(0)

hasIQs = Left(checkOne, 3) = "iq_"

Dim columnsToCopy As Collection
Set columnsToCopy = New Collection

If hasIQs Then
    ' paste inital column into temporary worksheet
    columnsToCopy.Add ShRef.Columns(1)
End If

' loop for each iq_ in the array
For arrayLoop = LBound(iq_Array) To UBound(iq_Array)
    ' Take copy of potential ref and adjust to standard if required
    checkStr = iq_Array(arrayLoop)
    If hasIQs And Left(checkStr, 3) <> "iq_" Then checkStr = "iq_" & checkStr

    ' Look for existence of corresponding column in local copy array
    pCol = 0
    For iCol = 2 To colNumb
        If checkStr = IQRef(iCol) Then
            pCol = iCol
            Exit For
        End If
    Next iCol

    If pCol > 0 Then
        ' Paste the corresponding column into the forming table
        columnsToCopy.Add ShRef.Columns(pCol)
    End If

Next arrayLoop

If columnsToCopy.Count > 1 Then      'data was added

    ' Copy table

    Dim unionVariable As Range

    Set unionVariable = columnsToCopy(1)


    For k = 2 To columnsToCopy.Count
        Set unionVariable = xlApp.Union(unionVariable, columnsToCopy(k))
    Next k

    unionVariable.Copy               ' all the data added to ShWork
```

The reason I'm looking into this, is because when I `Union(unionVariable, columnToCopy(k))` I'm not getting something that would be equivalent to Range("A:A","D:D","Z:Z") , instead I'm getting Range("A:Z").

Any help is appreciated

My full code:

```
    Option Explicit

    Private Sub averageScoreRelay()
        ' 1. Run from PPT and open an Excel file
        ' 2. Start at slide 1 and find a box that contains the words "iq_", if it has those words then it will have numbers after it like so "iq_43" or "iq_43, iq_56,iq_72".
        ' 3. find those words and numbers in the opened Excel file after splitting and re-formating string.
        ' 3. Copy column into a new sheets and repeat for all "iq_'s" until sheets 2 has a table.
        ' 4. Copy table from xl Paste Table into ppt
        ' 5. Do this for every slide

        'Timer start
        Dim StartTime As Double
        Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
        StartTime = Timer


        'Create variables
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
        Dim ShRef As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim pptPres As Object
        Dim colNumb As Long
        Dim rowNumb As Long

        ' Create new excel instance and open relevant workbook
        Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
        'xlApp.Visible = True 'Make Excel visible
        Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Andre Kunz\Desktop\Gate\Macros\averageScores\pptxlpratice\dummy2.xlsx", True, False, , , , True, Notify:=False) 'Open relevant workbook
        If xlWB Is Nothing Then                      ' may not need this if statement. check later.
            MsgBox ("Error retrieving Average Score Report, Check file path")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

        'Find # of iq's in workbook
        Set ShRef = xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        colNumb = ShRef.Cells(1, ShRef.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        rowNumb = ShRef.Cells(ShRef.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim IQRef() As String
        Dim iCol As Long
        Dim IQRngRef() As Range

        ReDim IQRef(colNumb)
        ReDim IQRngRef(colNumb)

        ' capture IQ refs locally
        For iCol = 2 To colNumb
            Set IQRngRef(iCol) = ShRef.Range(ShRef.Cells(1, iCol), ShRef.Cells(rowNumb, iCol))
            IQRef(iCol) = ShRef.Cells(1, iCol).Value
        Next iCol

        'Make pptPres the ppt active
        Set pptPres = PowerPoint.ActivePresentation

        'Create variables for the slide loop
        Dim pptSlide As Slide
        Dim Shpe As Shape
        Dim pptText As String
        Dim iq_Array As Variant
        Dim arrayLoop As Long
        Dim myShape As Object
        Dim i As Long
        Dim lRows As Long
        Dim lCols As Long
        Dim k As Long

        'Loop through each pptSlide and check for IQ text box, grab avgScore values and create pptTable
        For Each pptSlide In pptPres.Slides

            i = 0
            pptSlide.Select

            'searches through shapes in the slide
            For Each Shpe In pptSlide.Shapes

                If Not Shpe.HasTextFrame Then GoTo nextShpe 'boom, one less nested If statement
                If Not Shpe.TextFrame.HasText Then GoTo nextShpe ' boom, another nested If statement bites the dust

                'Set pptText as the Text in the box, then make it lowercase and trim Spaces and Enters
                pptText = Shpe.TextFrame.TextRange
                pptText = LCase(Replace(pptText, " ", vbNullString))
                pptText = Replace(Replace(Replace(pptText, vbCrLf, vbNullString), vbCr, vbNullString), vbLf, vbNullString)


                'Identify if within text there is "iq_"
                If InStr(1, pptText, "iq_") <= 0 Then GoTo nextShpe

                'set iq_Array as an array of the split iq's
                iq_Array = Split(pptText, ",")

                Dim hasIQs As Boolean
                Dim checkStr As String
                Dim pCol As Long
                Dim checkOne

            checkOne = iq_Array(0)

            hasIQs = Left(checkOne, 3) = "iq_"

            Dim columnsToCopy As Collection
            Set columnsToCopy = New Collection

            If hasIQs Then
                ' paste inital column into temporary worksheet
                columnsToCopy.Add ShRef.Columns(1)
            End If

            ' loop for each iq_ in the array
            For arrayLoop = LBound(iq_Array) To UBound(iq_Array)
                ' Take copy of potential ref and adjust to standard if required
                checkStr = iq_Array(arrayLoop)
                If hasIQs And Left(checkStr, 3) <> "iq_" Then checkStr = "iq_" & checkStr

                ' Look for existence of corresponding column in local copy array
                pCol = 0
                For iCol = 2 To colNumb
                    If checkStr = IQRef(iCol) Then
                        pCol = iCol
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next iCol

                If pCol > 0 Then
                    ' Paste the corresponding column into the forming table
                    columnsToCopy.Add ShRef.Columns(pCol)
                End If

            Next arrayLoop

            If columnsToCopy.Count > 1 Then      'data was added

                ' Copy table

                Dim unionVariable As Range

                Set unionVariable = columnsToCopy(1)


                For k = 2 To columnsToCopy.Count
                    Debug.Print k & " : " & unionVariable.Address & " + " & columnsToCopy(k).Address
                    Set unionVariable = xlApp.Union(unionVariable, columnsToCopy(k))
                    Debug.Print " --> " & unionVariable.Address
                Next k
                    unionVariable.Copy               ' all the data added to ShWork

tryAgain:

                    ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal
                    ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Activate

                    Set myShape = pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteHTML, Link:=msoFalse)

                    On Error GoTo tryAgain

                    'Set position:
                    myShape.Left = -200
                    myShape.Top = 150 + i
                    i = i + 150
                End If


nextShpe:

            Next Shpe

nextSlide:

        Next pptSlide

        xlWB.Close
        xlApp.Quit

        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True

        'End Timer
        SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
        MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

    End Sub
```

Output from Debugger:

```
2 : $A:$A + $B:$B
 --> $A:$B
3 : $A:$B + $AF:$AF
 --> $A:$B,$AF:$AF
2 : $A:$A + $C:$C
 --> $A:$A,$C:$C
2 : $A:$A + $D:$D
 --> $A:$A,$D:$D
3 : $A:$A,$D:$D + $L:$L
 --> $A:$A,$D:$D,$L:$L
```

Comment: Not fully digested your code, but in your `iCol` loop, it appears that if the value is found you set pCol equal to iCol (i.e. pCol>0). Then in your following If statement you add the column to the collection if pCol >0. As I said, I haven't followed all your code closely so I may have missed something.

Comment: I get an error on `ShRef.Columns(1).UsedRange`.  (I assume `ShRef` is a reference to a worksheet, but I'm not sure how you get a `UsedRange` property to exist on a column?!?!)  Or is `ShRef` some object in PowerPoint?  (I'm not too familiar with the PowerPoint object model.)  It might be best if you post enough code in your question so that we can tell what objects are in PowerPoint and what objects are in Excel.

Comment: @YowE3K Ouch, sorry I forgot to remove those. I was trying something out, and obviously it didn't work. So UsedRange has been removed. Also, there is a pastebin link with the full code up-top. SJR, you're right. I can just have that in the for loop, but it still didn't fix my problem unfortunately :(

Comment: You should include enough code **in the question itself** to resolve the issue - links to third-party sites are likely to "break" in the future, which means that the question would then become useless for future users of this site.

Comment: Your statement saying `If hasIQs And Left(checkStr, 3) <> "iq_" Then checkStr = "iq_" & checkStr` worries me - the boolean variable `hasIQs` is based solely on whether `Left(iq_Array(0), 3) = "iq_"` - should it possibly be based on **different** values of `iq_Array` and not just index 0?

Comment: @YowE3K this statement is right actually. "iq_" is a label that only need to exists in the beginning of a users input. I want eople to be able to input things like "iq_3,4,5,6" instead of having to input "iq_3,iq_4,iq_5,iq_6". The problem I'm having here is with the columnsToPaste collection and the unionVariable.Copy.

Comment: All I can suggest then is to try and narrow down the code to find **where** the error is occurring.  I'd recommend starting by adding, within your `For k` loop, a `Debug.Print k & " : " & unionVariable.Address & " + " & columnsToCopy(k).Address` immediately before the `Set unionVariable =` statement and a `Debug.Print " --> " & unionVariable.Address` immediately after it.  That will at least let you work out whether it is a specific `columnsToCopy(k)` that is causing the problem or whether it occurs on the very first `Union`.

Comment: @YowE3K I never used the Immediate window before, I like this :). So I get this: https://pastebin.com/qs4apMZA and I'm not really sure what to make of it. Could you give me a hand? It looks to me like everything is correct? Or are the commas supposed to be plus signs?

Comment: @Pinlop I'm sorry, but I'm not going to follow links to external sites (a) because I'm paranoid about viruses (especially if I am using my work computer) and (b) because external links may stop working in the future, which will then make your question useless to future users of the site, so the price for my help is a good, self-contained, question.  Add anything relevant from that external link into the question itself and I will have a look.

Comment: @YowE3K No problem, that's a cheap price to pay :). I just didn't know how to show you it without pastebin. I have updated the original question.

Comment: That output appears to be exactly what I would expect, e.g. starting with just column A and adding column B gives an address of `$A:$B`, and then taking that and adding column AF gives an address of `$A:$B,$AF:$AF`.  I don't think it is the union that is causing your problem, it seems more likely it is the copy/paste into PowerPoint.  (It may not support a paste of non-contiguous ranges.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another option doesn't have the additional overhead of creating a temporary workbook/worksheet.

**Note:** It may not be perfect -- in my testing it does not preserve cell background color but it does preserve text/font formats, and this appears consistent with the `PasteSpecial(ppPasteHtml)` method.

**Note also:** this assumes you can use a *Table* in PowerPoint to store the pasted data, and that all columns in your union range have the same number of rows. If you're just dumping the data in to a textbox or whatever sort of shape, this won't work.

But the idea is that once we have our "union", we can iterate over the `Areas`, and the `Columns` in each area, performing the `Copy` and `Paste` operation against each individual column.

Here is my data in Excel, I will create a union of the highlighted cells:

[image]

Here is the output in PowerPoint where I removed the borders from the table, note the text formatting preserved as well as cell alignment:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()
Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim tbl As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim unionRange As Range
Dim ar As Range, c As Long, i As Long

Set unionRange = Union([A1:B2], [D1:D2], [F1:F2])

Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
ppt.Visible = True
Set pres = ppt.ActivePresentation
Set sld = pres.Slides(1)

' Create initial table with only 1 column
With unionRange
    Set tbl = sld.Shapes.AddTable(.Rows.Count, 1)
End With
For Each ar In unionRange.Areas()
    For c = 1 To ar.Columns.Count
        i = i + 1
        With tbl.Table
            ' Add columns as you iterate the columns in your unionRange
            If .Columns.Count < i Then .Columns.Add
            .Columns(i).Cells.Borders(ppBorderBottom).Transparency = 1
            .Columns(i).Cells.Borders(ppBorderTop).Transparency = 1
            .Columns(i).Select
            ar.Columns(c).Copy  '// Copy the column from Excel
            ppt.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("Paste") '// Paste the values to PowerPoint
        End With
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Maybe more efficient to handle the `Areas` like so:

```
For Each ar In unionRange.Areas()
    c = ar.Columns.Count
    Dim tCol
    tCol = .Columns.Count
    With tbl.Table
        ' Add columns as you iterate the columns in your unionRange
        While .Columns.Count < (tCol + c)
            .Columns.Add
        Wend
        .Columns(tCol).Cells.Borders(ppBorderBottom).Transparency = 1
        .Columns(tCol).Cells.Borders(ppBorderTop).Transparency = 1
        .Columns(tCol).Select
        ar.Copy  '// Copy the columns in THIS Area object from Excel
        ppt.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("Paste") '// Paste the values to PowerPoint
    End With
Next
```

But I still think performance on large data set will suffer vs the other answer.

Comment: I was able to implement this and make it work with my code, but unfortunately it ran slower than creating a new sheet and making the table the then copying it over to powerpoint. Maybe because of how many time it pastes? I'm really not sure... It's a bummer, because this is a really good work around! I've also been trying a different way that I can't figure out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46851310/creating-a-table-out-of-values-stored-in-an-array?noredirect=1#comment80653173_46851310  Thank you for putting so much thought into this!

Comment: Yeah I didn't test any of it for performance. If the other answer is *better* in terms of performance, you should probably Accept that other answer. I think your suspicion is correct: performance will take a hit if there is a large number of iteration (I only had 4 columns in my test case). If there are many colums, then that is a lot of manipulation of the Shapes and table in PowerPoint, plus many `Paste` operation. In those cases, the other answer will perform better as the overhad of creating new Excel is less than the iteration overhead.

Comment: This could probably be improved a bit to better handle `Areas` consisting of 2 or more columns, to reduce the iterative overhead, but still if there are very many areas in the union, then the other answer probably more efficient solution.

Comment: You're right, my use has many iterations. Sometimes 40 cells. With the other link that I posted, I tried storing each cell into it's unique array slot, and made the array 2d to resemble excel. I have all the values in there, but putting them together in order to paste into powerpoint has become trivial. Do you have any ideas for that?

Comment: If it's just plain text/numeric values you're after (and you don't concern with formatting, etc.) then there's many possible ways you could do that writing to a text stream in memory, using the string `Join` method on a vector array, etc. None of these would require the overhead of `Copy`, nor of an extra workbook, and as a result they would also reduce the iterative overhead required to paste each "column" individually. I would explore that option, just building an array or text stream and dumping that in to PowerPoint. But it is not something I can help with presently.

Comment: I will look into these, I appreciate the help again!

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be caused by the pasting of the non-contiguous range into PowerPoint.

I don't know enough PowerPoint VBA to know whether it has some other paste method you could use, but a work-around would be to create a new Excel worksheet containing just the info you want to copy, and then to copy that worksheet to PowerPoint:

```
            '...
            Next k
                unionVariable.Copy               ' all the data added to ShWork
                'Create a temporary sheet (the workbook is being closed without saving
                'so the temporary worksheet will be "lost" after we finish)
                xlWB.Worksheets.Add Before:=xlWB.Worksheets(1)
                'Paste the data into the temporary sheet
                xlWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                'Copy the temporary sheet
                xlWB.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy

tryAgain:

                ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal
                '...
```

Comment: I think you are right. Sad :(, that is how I had it and I was trying to make it faster by using arrays and collections. Too bad. Thank you for all the help

Comment: I haven't been able to find any other method (I tried a few things using the `CommandBars.ExecuteMSO`, which is my *go-to* when it comes to copy/paste between different Applications, but seems that nothing can handle non-contiguous ranges the same as Excel. I did figure out a different workaround, though, below.