# Creating a Table out of .Values stored in an Array

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm new to working with 2D arrays, and would like to get better.

Currently everything is going well, my array is populating like I want it to, but I can't figure out how to get it into a table.

Right now I have each cell's value stored in it's corresponding array slot. So `Range(B1:B4)` is stored in `IQRef(1, 2), IQRef(2, 2), IQRef(3, 2), IQRef(4, 2)`.

For what I'm doing, storing the Range directly is not an option. PowerPoint issues with pasting non-contiguous ranges...

So what I want to be able to do is create a table out of these values that I will be pasting into PowerPoint.

This was my failed attempt at "concatenating" all the individual values stored in the array: `Set unionVariable = xlApp.Union(IQRef(1, 2), IQRef(2, 2), IQRef(3, 2), IQRef(4, 2), IQRef(1, 7), IQRef(2, 7), IQRef(3, 7), IQRef(4, 7))`
It failed, obviously, because IQRef isn't a Range, and Union only takes ranges.

So my question is, how would I get the values I have in my array into a table?

```
Public Sub tableArray()

    'Timer start
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
    StartTime = Timer

    'Create variables
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ShRef As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim pptPres As Object
    Dim colNumb As Long
    Dim rowNumb As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myShape As Object

    Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ' Create new excel instance and open relevant workbook
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    'xlApp.Visible = True 'Make Excel visible
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("filePath", True, False, , , , True, Notify:=False) 'Open relevant workbook
    If xlWB Is Nothing Then                      ' may not need this if statement. check later.
        MsgBox ("Error retrieving file, Check file path")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Find # of iq's in workbook
    Set ShRef = xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    colNumb = ShRef.Cells(1, ShRef.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    rowNumb = ShRef.Cells(ShRef.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim IQRef() As String
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim iRow As Long

    ReDim IQRef(1 To rowNumb, 2 To colNumb)
    ' capture IQ refs locally
    For iRow = 1 To rowNumb
        For iCol = 2 To colNumb
            IQRef(iRow, iCol) = ShRef.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
        Next iCol
    Next iRow
    'Make pptPres the ppt active
    Set pptPres = PowerPoint.ActivePresentation

    'Create variables for the slide loop
    Dim pptSlide As Slide
    Dim unionVariable

    Set unionVariable = xlApp.Union(IQRef(1, 2), IQRef(2, 2), IQRef(3, 2), IQRef(4, 2), IQRef(1, 7), IQRef(2, 7), IQRef(3, 7), IQRef(4, 7))

    For Each pptSlide In pptPres.Slides

        ' Copy table
        unionVariable.Copy                       ' copy unioneVariable that should be a table

        ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal
        ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Activate

        Set myShape = pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteHTML, Link:=msoFalse) 'Should paste unionVariable's table

        'Set position:
        myShape.Left = -200
        myShape.Top = 150 + i
        i = i + 150

    Next pptSlide

    xlWB.Close
    xlApp.Quit

    Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'End Timer
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
    MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: if the range and array are the same size/shape you can just assign all it's values at once. For example (assuming IQRef is 1 to 4, 1 to 1); Placing IQRef into B1:B4 would be `range("B1:B4") = IQRef`

Comment: @Zerk IQRef is storing a big database of numbers. I want to just copy over two columns. So IQRef is 1 to 4, 1 to 100. I would need something that did what this is saying but isn't doing `Set Range(A1:B4) = IQRef(1, 2), IQRef(2, 2), IQRef(3, 2), IQRef(4, 2), IQRef(1, 7), IQRef(2, 7), IQRef(3, 7), IQRef(4, 7)`

Comment: @Zerk so I got this to work:     `Range("A1:A1") = IQRef(1, 2)
    Range("A2:A2") = IQRef(2, 2)
    Range("B1:B1") = IQRef(1, 7)
    Range("B2:B2") = IQRef(2, 7)
Range("A1:B2").Copy`
But this isn't really going to help me

Comment: Why not loop through IQRef and feed the values you want into a smaller array that matches requirements? then it can just be one range value assignment

Comment: @Zerk I think this might work but bare with me please, I'm still very new to coding in general. Just as a test, I first 'Dim testArray()' and 'ReDim testArray(1 To 4, 2 To 4)' then I have the new array set to only the values  want from IQRef like so:`testArray(1,2) = IQRef(1, 2) testArray(2,2) = IQRef(2, 2) testArray(1,3) = IQRef(1,7) testArray(2,3) = IQRef(2,7)` then I make `Range("A1:B2") = testArray`then I try `testArray.Copy` and it gives me error "Invalid qualifier". What am I doing wrong here? Also, how will I be able to set the Range to be dynamic depending on columns/rows in testArray?

Comment: @Zerk I figured it out.... I was copying testArray instead of Range("A1:B2")... But the second part of that question still stands. How would I make the Range dynamic depending on howmany columns and rows there are in testArray?

Comment: @Zerk third time is the charm.... Just realized this won't work because setting those ranges actually overrides the data in my workbook. and the whole point of trying to use arrays is to not have to create a Sheet2

Comment: Based on the comments it sounds like you'll revise your approach. To answer the question on dynamic ranges i prefer to use the cells referencing approach, and assuming testArray is our data we want to paste and x is our target, it'd be along the lines of `range(x.cells(1,1),x.cells(ubound(testArray,1),ubound(testArray,2))) = testArray`

Comment: @Zerk Ah, yes. That is looking very familiar, and quite similar to what I had before starting to go down this other route. Thank you for your help :)